# data-url with {{ uploadUrl }} not swapping in scope url (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery fileupload to post a file to a url. In my controller I have something like this to generate the url I am going to post to.

```
uploadService.getUploadURL($scope.projectId).then(function (url) {
     $scope.uploadUrl = url.uploadUrl;
});
```

Then in my view I have this to fill in the data-url

```
<span id="btn-browse" class="btn btn-success btn-file">Browse<input type="file" name="file" data-url="{{uploadUrl}}" multiple upload /></span>
```

The problem I am running into is that when I post a file it ends up using the url, http://localhost/%7B%7BuploadUrl%7D%7D  as it is not replacing {{uploadUrl}}.

I know this is most likely very basic and I am missing something simple. If anyone can help out with this or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!

** Per the request below for upload code **

From the upload controller

```
$scope.upload = function () {
    uploadService.upload();
}
```

From the upload service

```
upload: function () {
    $.each(_files, function (ix, file) {
         file.submit();
    });
    this.clear();
}
```

It is also worth mentioning that the jquery fileupload is implemented in a directive like so:

```
$(element).fileupload({
    dataType: "text",
    add: function (e, data) {
         uploadService.add(data);
    },

    progressall: function (e, data) {
         var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
         uploadService.setProgress(progress);
    },

    done: function (e, data) {
         uploadService.uploadDone();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code related to file post?

Comment: Vinary see the edit I made above.

Comment: May be by the time you convert your element to jquery file upload, uploadUrl might have not been resolved. try `$timeout(function () { $(element.fileupload({})) })`

Comment: If $timeout solution doesn't work for you, please create a plnkr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have created a directive , when file upload is created the url is not loaded yet.

What you can do is to add watch inside the directive for `uploadUrl` and if it has changed it's value create the file uploader using jquery.

```
$scope.watch('uploadUrl',function(newValue, oldValue ){
   if(newValue!==oldValue){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(element).fileupload({
        dataType: "text",
        add: function (e, data) {
           uploadService.add(data);
         },

         progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            uploadService.setProgress(progress);
         },

         done: function (e, data) {
            uploadService.uploadDone();
         }
     });
    });
   }
});
```

Comment: This worked although I ended up not doing it this way as I needed to update the url on a per file basis. But this solution solved the problem stated up above.